# Pinging between two different vm's with different subnet on same host

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ping, host

I am running a windows machine and i am running virtualbox on it

I have two VM's for cent os.

I want the two VM's to ping each other but they should have different subnets.

I am not really sure how to do it thus posting this question. I am really not concerned if they can connect to the internet or not, i want them in different subnets.

I tried by using two different internal networks but was not able to ping.

Thanks for you help in advance, really appreciate it

Comment: Windows XP supports IP forwarding. You might want to try if your Windows support it too. Here's the link to Microsoft knowledgebase regarding this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315236

Answer (score 1):

First of all, internal network is an exclusive type of network so you can never reach another machine if they are on different network.

For machines in different subnet to be connected each other, you should have a router between them. So you will need 1 more virtual machine. Just use "Bridget Adapter" mode for the network type at all machine and  assign the IP as you like. Just make sure that the router is located in the middle logically.  Machine A - Router - Machine B. To create a router machine you can use ubuntu OS. You can see it here : 
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html